# Is there an in-universe scientific explanation for the Engineers having white skin?

Tags: movie, alien-franchise, prometheus

In *Prometheus*, the Engineers have very pale white skin.

Is it explained why? Has an in-universe scientific explanation been given?

Comment: They don't get out very much

Comment: Hi Charles, I took the liberty to edit your question a bit so that it doesn't seem like you're asking for "real world" science, which would be off-topic here. Asking for in-universe reasons is perfectly fine. If you disagree with my edit, you can [edit] your post further, no offense taken. Cheers :)

Comment: "*They are men - and yet not men. Their skin is snow-white. 
Their features heavy and classical - as if Rodin's Thinker 
had risen from his seat. Their smooth heads are earless and 
hairless. Their glittering eyes entirely black.*" - https://archive.org/stream/pdfy-9NMTSgzvy2U3U-oz/Alien-Engineers-ORIGINAL-PROMETHEUS-SCRIPT_djvu.txt

Comment: I didn't ask for description but for explenation why is that.

Comment: @Charles - Indeed. Which is why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer to the question.

Comment: A movie analyst I am following thinks that the Engineers were made to look like the marble statues from antic Greece and Rome, so we could supposed these statues were made to represent the Engineers and prove they went on Earth before.

Comment: For hat it is worth, https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Engineer `The Engineers are extremely pale-white, hairless and humanoid due to their subterranean nature` but no clue where they got that.